Is it possible to call Flask based server-side api in Simulink
I looked up how to integrate Python with Simulink (see link), however this is for an actual algorithm. What I'm trying to achieve is create a Matlab function or system (class) that calls Python rest api implemented in Flask (Server-side), but there couple of issue :

Attempt to extract field 'run' from 'mxArray'.
When instantiating the Flask(name_) object, it appears to be an issue

Any insights ?!
